# X11Fowarding not working on Arch Linux ARM

Tags: ssh, arch-linux, x11, xorg, osx

I am trying to setup X11Forwarding between my Arch Linux ARM server and my OSX computer.

I am accessing the server locally (always).

**/etc/ssh/ssh_config:**

```
X11Forwarding yes
AddressFamily any
PermitRootLogin yes
X11UseLocalhost yes
```

**ssh -X -A root@myserver.local -v**

```
...
X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0
...
```

xorg-xauth is installed so i assume that this problem can be excluded. Furthermore X11 starts smoothly on the client side when connecting via. SSH.

Why is it failing?

**UPDATE**

Unfortunately i have been editing the wrong file all along, which should have been `sshd_config` and not `ssh_config`.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 shots:
1. Perhaps login as root is denied (that's the default setting on many systems and it is pretty reasonable). Did you tried with a different user?
2. Did you try sshing with ssh -Y?

Comment: I tried a secondary user, unfortunately the same problem. I have tried with `-Y` with the same result..

Comment: Does journalctl -r --unit sshd reveal anything interesting?

Comment: Unfortunately no, it looks very clean..

Comment: Did you try setting X11UseLocalhost?

Comment: I have just tried, same result. It should be enough to `systemctl restart  sshd`?

Comment: systemctl reload might be required to reread the conf file. Not sure if it is in the case of sshd.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26271/discussion-between-javacake-and-daves-tux).